# SwiftUI Rotation Problem: When I rotate my simulator, the content of my SwiftUI file doesn't shown

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I have a custom splash screen which is called `SplashScreenView`. After animations on splash screen, my home screen is shown which is called `LocationTabView`. `LocationTabView` contains a `NavigationView`. I can see my home screen after splash screen without any problem, but when I rotate the simulator, the content of `LocationTabView` is doesn't shown. How can I solve this problem?

Here is my `SplashScreenView` :

```
struct SplashScreenView: View {
    @State private var orientation = UIDeviceOrientation.unknown
    
    @State var isHomeRootScreen = false
    @State var scaleAmount: CGFloat = 1
    @State var welcomeText: String = ""
    @State var helloWelcome:String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ geometry in
        ZStack {
            
            //Color("background")
            Image("background2").resizable()
                .aspectRatio(geometry.size, contentMode: .fill)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            if isHomeRootScreen {
                    LocationTabView()
                
            } else {
                VStack {
                    Text(welcomeText)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.17, green: 0.45, blue: 0.22))
                        .font(.custom("Avenir", size: 50))
                        .bold()
                    Image(helloWelcome).resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit).frame(width: 300)
                    Image("rickandmorty")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .scaleEffect(scaleAmount)
                        .frame(width: 400)
                }
            }
        }}
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .onAppear{
            //shrink the icon
            helloWelcome = getWelcomeText()
            withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 1)) {
                scaleAmount = 0.8
            }
            //enlarge the icon
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.8).delay(1)) {
                if orientation.isPortrait {
                    scaleAmount = 100} else {
                        scaleAmount = 180
                    }
            }
            // go to home screen
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.8) {
                isHomeRootScreen = true
                }
            }
    }
    
    private func getWelcomeText() -> String {
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isFirstLaunch") {
            return "hello"
        } else {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isFirstLaunch")
            return "welcome"
        }
    }
    private func getimgText() -> String {
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isFirstLaunch") {
            return "hello"
        } else {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isFirstLaunch")
            return "welcome"
        }
    }
    
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            SplashScreenView()
        }
    }
    
    struct DeviceRotationViewModifier: ViewModifier {
        let action: (UIDeviceOrientation) -> Void

        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            content
                .onAppear()
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
                    action(UIDevice.current.orientation)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

These are the screenshots from my simulator:

[image]

After I rotate:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you include a [mre]?